# Adding additional columns to standard related list in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, related-list, lightning-app-builder

I have a requirement to display version number and some other fields from files object in Approval object .
I am using the files related list-Single . I tried using enhanced list and number of records to display as 10 .But when I go to page layout the files related list displays " This list is not customizable " .

Do I have to go building up a custom component or any OOB feature can help me .

Thanks in advance